# chartjs time chart label reversed

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I am using chartjs to draw line chart. yaxis is time. But I want time in only hours and minutes.  Since the data has to be a Date object and only hours and minutes (Time object) is not supported by javascript and moment.js, I am setting the date to today's date and 12:00am and add the  minutes to it as shown below:

```
  var date = moment().startOf('day')    
    date.add(value, 'minutes');
```

Chart is drawn with hours and minutes. but, my yaxis labels are reversed. instead of 01:00 (starting at (0,0), 04:00.. 15:00, it prints the labels from maximum time to min time like 15:00 being the starting step(at 0,0) ..

my yaxis configuration is like this:

```
yAxes : [ {
          type: 'time',
          unit: 'minute',
          tooltipFormat: 'H:mm',
          time : {
              displayFormats: {
                  hour: 'H:mm'
              }
          }
      }]
```

I tried setting min, max values also but it is not helping. Can somebody help me fix this

Comment: Did you try `beginAtZero`?

Comment: Can you add a JSFiddle?

Comment: I could achieve the same result by using call back functions without using time chart. Thanks for your help